# By dumping a python list, creating a python ".py" file which returns the same python list

Tags: python, list, csv, numpy

I have a ".csv" file which involves more than 1 million rows of data.

In python, I have to process this data. In this case, after each running, I have to wait almost 1 minute in order to load the data.

In order not to wait for such a long time, automatically I want to create a ".py" file which has the numpy array list of this ".csv" file, and returns this value.

How can I create such a ".py" file automatically with a python script?

Thanks,

Comment: Check out [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NumPy's [save()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [load()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html):

```
import numpy as np
```

Save:

```
np.save('my_array.npy', my_array)
```

Load again:

```
my_array = np.load('my_array.npy')
```

This is a simple and likely a pretty fast solution.

You can use [savez()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) if you have more than one array.
Maybe compression with [savez_compressed](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed) can be useful. Just try if it works for you.